# How to test Outlook with cypress (integration)

Tags: javascript, outlook, automated-tests, cypress

I need to test outlook integration with my app.
The thing is that is no possible to enter in login tab with cypress, after cy.visit(//) a new window is opened and the test is gone, no fail is displayed.
Any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.